# How to insert percentage of completion of FFI function?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, ffi

I am trying to develop android application using flutter. I used **Flutter FFI** to interface and call function from **.C (C language)** files. Is there any way to show **percentage of completion of function execution** which called from **.C** language?

I used multi threading to show normal loading screen. But I want to show percentage of function completion which called from C.

Comment: Unrelated to what your asking, but more the terminology you're using in your question and your tags. Is this **Dart** or **Flutter** ffi. Are you using Flutter?

Comment: If you have a mechanism for obtaining progress values from your C code, it's simple. You likely don't have that. If you want implement something like this you would need to use additional threads.

Comment: Yeah.I am using flutter to make android app. I didn't get what do you mean by additional threads. Can you please explain it How can I achieve desired functionality with additional threads. ?

Comment: Perhaps not additional C thread, but you at the very least need another Dart isolate. In your C code, you need to update a progress variable. So in one isolate you call your actual C function. In your other isolate you do a continuous loop to check that progress variable and update your loader. Access access to that progress variable needs to be done in a thread safe manner.